# Swift DateFormatter properties not changing

Tags: ios, swift, date, localization, nsdateformatter

This is a very puzzling situation, I've read lots of documentation on the [NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter) but I can't seem to be able to set the localized date format template. Using the `dateFormat` property works but using `setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate` does not, essentially I have the following code in swift 5.3:

First in a terminal open a swift REPL and type the following:

```swift
import Foundation // takes a few secs

var ftt = DateFormatter()
ftt.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
ftt.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("'Deliver on' MMMM d 'at' h:mm a 'sharp'")
```

After running I get the following output:

```sh
ftt: DateFormatter = {
  baseNSFormatter@0 = {
    baseNSObject@0 = {
      isa = NSDateFormatter
    }
  }
  _attributes = 3 key/value pairs {
    [0] = {
      key = "locale"
      value =
    }
    [1] = {
      key = "formatterBehavior"
      value = Int64(1040)
    }
    [2] = {
      key = "dateFormat"
      value = "MMMM d, h:mm a"
    }
  }
  _formatter = {}
  _counter = 0
  _cacheGeneration = 3
  _behavior = 0
}
```

As you can see from the output neither the `locale` or the `dateFormat` have been stored. Formatting a date results in the following:

```swift
 14> ftt.string(from: Date())
$R1: String = "October 21, 8:19 PM"
```

I've made sure that the [locale identifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslocale) is correct, I've followed a few tutorials on DateFormatter such as:

- https://learnappmaking.com/swift-date-datecomponents-dateformatter-how-to/#string-to-date-parsing-dates-timezones
- https://nsdateformatter.com

And checked usage of the `setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate` as well as [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter/1417087-setlocalizeddateformatfromtempla) and make sure to call it after setting `locale`.

If I assign the `dateFormat` property directly I get the desired result:

```
17> ftt.dateFormat = "'Deliver on' MMMM d 'at' h:mm a 'sharp'"
ftt: DateFormatter = {
  baseNSFormatter@0 = {
    baseNSObject@0 = {
      isa = NSDateFormatter
    }
  }
  _attributes = 3 key/value pairs {
    [0] = {
      key = "locale"
      value =
    }
    [1] = {
      key = "formatterBehavior"
      value = Int64(1040)
    }
    [2] = {
      key = "dateFormat"
      value = "\'Deliver on\' MMMM d \'at\' h:mm a \'sharp\'"
    }
  }
  _formatter =
  _counter = 0
  _cacheGeneration = 2
  _behavior = 0
}

18> ftt.string(from: Date())
$R2: String = "Deliver on October 21 at 8:25 PM sharp"
```

What's going on?! am I missing something obvious? I want to understand the behavior.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstand what `setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate` does. [Its documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter/1417087-setlocalizeddateformatfromtempla) says:

> Calling this method is equivalent to, but not necessarily implemented as, setting the `dateFormat` property to the result of calling the `dateFormat(fromTemplate:options:locale:)` method, passing no options and the locale property value.

Now what does [`dateFormat(fromTemplate:options:locale:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter/1408112-dateformat) do? Lets see:

> #### Return Value
>
> A localized date format string representing the date format components given in template, arranged appropriately for the locale specified by locale.
>
> The returned string may not contain exactly those components given in template, but may—for example—have locale-specific adjustments applied.

So `dateFormat(fromTemplate:options:locale:)` tries to *localise* the template to a specified locale. If no locale is specified, it uses `Locale.current`. For example:

```
// this produces "MM/dd/yyyy"
DateFormatter.dateFormat(fromTemplate: "yyyy dd MM", options: 0, locale: Locale(identifier: "en-US"))
```

That explains why it removes all the quoted strings in your format, because the localisation engine doesn't recognise your quoted strings, so to produce a "localised" version of your date format, the best it can do is to remove them. As far as it is concerned, the quoted strings could be in a different language!

So it's not that `setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate` did not change `dateFormat`. It *did* change it to `"MMMM d, h:mm a"`, which is what iOS thinks is the best "localised" version of the format

```
"'Deliver on' MMMM d 'at' h:mm a 'sharp'"
```

In this situation, you should set `dateFormat` directly, rather than `setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate`, as you don't want a localised date format.

Comment: Hi Sweeper, thank you for you answer, yes that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Yes my incorrect assumption was that it'd try to localize the 'quoted' words to the formatters locale and preserve them as part of the formatted string.

Answer (score 1):

The issue there is that the order of the date components in template does not make a difference. You are suppose just to pass the components and how it will be displayed depends on the locale.

```
let ftt = DateFormatter()
ftt.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
ftt.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("dMMMMhm")
ftt.dateFormat  // "MMMM d, h:mm a"
ftt.string(from: Date())  // "October 22, 12:45 AM"

ftt.locale = Locale(identifier: "pt_BR")
ftt.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("MMMMdysmH")
ftt.dateFormat  // "d 'de' MMMM 'de' y HH:mm:ss"
ftt.string(from: Date())  // "22 de outubro de 2020 00:45:36"
```

Comment: Hi Leo, thank you for your answer. I had it all wrong! That makes sense, if I add/remove "components" only those that are present in the template string will be part of the formatted string.